# How do I call a -(void) method from a -(IBaction) method?

Tags: objective-c

I have a void method that is responsible for a URL and I want to call it using a IBAction (UIbutton) to update/ change the URL and thus the content of my view.

```
- (void) retrieveData {
   _NSMutableDictionary = contains parts of the url 
   NSString * thisUrlGetsPutTogetherFromKeysInTheMutableDict = @"www.myurl.url";
}


-(IBAction)btnChangeUrl:(UIButton *)sender {
   ADD something to the _NSMutableDictionary
   Call "retrieveData" to update and re-load the URL.
}
```

I've tried googling for answers before but I just can't seem to find clear instructions on how I should call retrieveData. Still a beginner. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: please learn more about the language first. how to call a method should be in first or second lesson

Comment: Where did you hijack this code from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[self retrieveData];`

Should work